# Getting from San Francisco (Union Square) to Oakland Airport by public transport

Tags: public-transport, san-francisco

How do I get from San Francisco (Union Square area) to Oakland Airport?  Can I take BART the entire way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can take the [Fremont–Daly City line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fremont%E2%80%93Daly_City_line) from the [Montgomery Street Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_Street_Station) to the [Oakland Coliseum Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oakland_Coliseum_Station). From the Oakland Coliseum Station you can take the [Coliseum-Oakland Airport line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coliseum%E2%80%93Oakland_International_Airport_line) to the airport.

BART map:

[image]

Comment: The Dublin-Pleasanton line (blue) also works runs from downtown SF to Coliseum/Oakland Airport.